# Is it possible to have two same styles with different values?

Tags: android, styles

I need to have different styles in my app, because it has two languages, so the font and sizes are different.
Is it possible to have these two styles and the app use the style that is related to the selected language, and when the language is changed, it choose the other style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using below code, you can do this

```
res/
values/   
    styles.xml  (Default style)
values-ar/  
    styles.xml  (Specific style for Arabic)
```